# Websites which offer 'Reserve Tickets - Pay Later' option

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I am a Bangladesh national. I need some websites which allow to reserve a ticket but make the payment afterwards (after a day or some time).

Comment: Very few 3rd party websites book "on hold" reservations, they almost all require full prepayment.  One might guess that you are wanting proof of travel for a visa application?

Comment: yes there are some websites. You can have a look a flydubai and yatra

Comment: [Emirates does this](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/hold-my-fare/hold-my-fare.aspx); but it depends where you are booking from. Try visiting their website. If nothing else, an agent can do this easily for you.

Comment: AA does it too. But it would be good if the OP explains why they want this, as it may not be necessary, or there may be other workarounds